# Autoloading classes

Tags: php, oop, autoload

I have created a Database class named Database.class.php in my includes folder. This is my code:

```
require_once 'includes/smarty/Smarty.class.php';
require_once 'includes/admin.functions.php';

function __autoload($class) {
    require_once 'includes/'.$class.'.class.php';
}

try {
    $db = Database::getInstance(); 
} catch (PDOException $e) { die('Error connecting to database.'); }
```

Is there anything wrong with this code? The first 2 includes works fine, I'm only getting a "class Database not found" error.

Does autoload only work when creating new object? If so, is there a workaround for singletons? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT:
When manually including, it works. So it's really related to the autoloading..

Comment: print out a debugging message inside your __autoload function just before the require_once... make sure that part is working.

Comment: Autoloading should work fine here. Does `includes/Database.class.php` really exist and define a `Database` class? You are 100% sure about that?

Comment: I think he would get an error if the file doesn't exist so I'm thinking maybe there's not a class named Database in there.

Comment: I've put an echo in the autoload function, but it's not executing. Yes, I'm 100% sure there is a file named Database.class.php in the includes folder which contains a class named Database. Strange...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php says autoload doesn't work in CLI interactive mode... I assume this isn't the case, but worth mentioning.

Comment: How can you check if that is enabled? I'm using a shared hosting account and this info doesn't seem to be in phpinfo.

Comment: It might not call `__autoload`, but anything [registered via `spl_autoload`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) works just fine in interactive mode.  e: If you're running the script through a web server, you aren't in interactive mode.  :)

Comment: Are you using a filesystem that's case-sensitive?  On Windows case doesn't matter too much but on *IX the case has to be correct.  So your Database class must be defined in a file called Database.class.php and not database.class.php, DATABASE.CLASS.PHP or anything else you can think of.  Also, is your autoload function being invoked at all?  Have it echo something at the start before it tries to include the specified class.  Finally, on an unrelated matter, you really ought to do some validation in __autoload of the class name being passed.

Comment: No, the function is not invoked: I've tried echo'ing already. Yup, I've also checked the filenames already... everything is correct, including capital letters.

Comment: Double check that there is not another `__autoload()` function. If there is and it is defined after your function above it will override your version.

Comment: Nope, there isn't another autoload()-function. Maybe I should just forget about autoloading and including it manually :(

Comment: Smarty registers an autoload with `spl_autoload_register` so to use Smarty in conjunction with your autoloader you will need to use `spl_autoload_register` too.

Comment: Ooh, that's what likely is wrong! Thank you very much! Can you add this as an answer so I can accept that answer? EDIT: Tested it, the code works fine when not including Smarty :) Tyvm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smarty registers an autoload function with [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). If you have your own  autoload function you must register it with `spl_autoload_register` too if you want them to work together.